# OAuthWebSecurity Extend Facebook Data (Firstname and Lastname)

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am using OAuthWebSecurity to make my MVC application Facebook login ready. Everything works as expected.
However, the provider only return the Facebook username (email address) back to my client. I like to also receive the Firstname and the Lastname but did not find any example how to do this with OAuthWebSecurity.

Is it possible to extend the Facebook provider without make use of the big Facebook sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some more research I find out that it is the easiest way to just use the Facebook SDK and use following code fregment to access this information:

```
     var client = new FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);
     dynamic me = client.Get("me");
     string firstName = me.first_name;
     string lastName = me.last_name;
     string email = me.email;
     string gender = me.gender;
```

It would be much more complicated to extend the Facebook OAuth provider.